# Modify URL-strings in CSV file - Output file contains each character in individual cell

Tags: python, url, csv

I am trying to write a function which allows me to remove certain elements from URLs. These URLs are stored in a CSV called `Backlink_Test`. I would like to iterate over each item in that list of URLs, remove the unwanted elements from the URL, and then add the modified URLs to a new list, which is then stored in a new CSV called `Cleaned_URLs`.

The code is working to the extent that I can open the source file, run the loop and then store the results in the destination file. However, I am encountering quite an annoying problem: in the destination file, the URLs are stored **with each character in an individual cell**, rather than the whole URL in once cell.

This surprised me as I did a little test where I literally copied the contents from CSV to another (without modifying anything) and words with multiple characters were stored just fine. So my suspicion is that the for-loop creates the problem?

Any help / insight would be much appreciated! Code below, and screenshot of destination file attached.

```
import csv

new_strings = []    

#replace unwanted elements and add cleaned strings to new list
with open("Backlink_Test.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for string in reader:
        string = str(string) 
        string = string.replace("www.", "").replace("http://", "").replace("https://", "")
        new_strings.append(string)

new_strings.sort()
print new_strings #for testing only; will be removed once function is working

cleaned_file = open("Cleaned_URLS.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(cleaned_file)
writer.writerows(new_strings)
cleaned_file.close()
```

[image: Screenshot of destination file]

Here is now the working code:

```
import csv

new_strings = []    

#replace unwanted elements and add cleaned strings to new list
with open("Backlink_Test.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for string in reader:
        string = str(string) 
        string = string.replace("www.", "").replace("http://", "").replace("https://", "")
        new_strings.append(string)

new_strings.sort()
print new_strings

cleaned_file = open("Cleaned_URLS.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(cleaned_file)
for url in new_strings:
    writer.writerow([url])

cleaned_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csvwriter.writerows` expects an iterable of `rows`. A `row` is an iterable of `cells`.

You're feeding it with a list of strings. Since string is a list of letters, every letter is considered a `cell` in your example -- and it's exactly what gets written.

What you're doing wrong is assuming `csv.reader` outputs strings. It outputs `rows`.

**Update**:

```
for url in urls:
    writer.writerow([url])
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean. What would you use instead of using csv.reader then?

Comment: I'd probably go with something like that. It looks like you don't have CSV file -- there's only one column -- but it illustrates proper use of the API.

Comment: Thank you so much, that works perfectly fine! Last bit I need to clean is that all urls in the destination file are now in `[]` but I assume there is no way around that?

Comment: Of course there is a way around that. Just don't do `string = str(string)` -- it flattens the csv row (a list) to a string representation of it. Please consider this: `str([1, 2, 3])` => `"[1, 2, 3]"`.

Answer (score 1):

That's what Python does when you loop over a string instead of a list. Examine the return value from `csv.reader()` and adjust your code accordingly. In particular, `string = str(string)` is flattening your input.

Comment: I understand, and it makes sense. Can you tell me how I should adjust the code in order to get the input right and the output as URL-strings? Thanks!